# Specific of the python's if/else one liner argument substitution

Tags: python, ternary-operator

Can anyone explain why:

```
>>> print 1,2 if 0 else 3,4
1 3 4
```

but:

```
>>> print(1,2) if 0 else 3,4
3 4
```

or maybe this is not connected with this condition at all?

Comment: Because the first is `print 1, (2 if 0 else 3), 4` and the second is `print ((1, 2) if 0 else 3), 4` - see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing. It's not clear which part you find surprising.

Comment: That's the reason why you should use print with brackets. To avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example gives three items to `print` which are separated by commas:

```
1
2 if 0 else 3
4
```

You could put the parentheses in different places and get the same result:

```
print 1, (2 if 0 else 3), 4
```

If you want to have the tuple behavior, you can use parentheses there:

```
print (1, 2) if 0 else (3, 4)
```

The problem, of course, is that it prints as a tuple instead of separate arguments.  Really, the best thing is either to use `from __future__ import print_function` and use `print(*((1, 2) if 0 else (3, 4)))` or to have a whole `if`-`else` block:

```
if 0:
    print 1, 2
else:
    print 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> print evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting
>   object to standard output.

So we just have to figure out that these expressions are in your case.

`print 1,2 if 0 else 3,4` is equivalent to `print 1, (2 if 0 else 3), 4`.
print statement receives three "arguments", first and third are constant expression, second one contains ternary statement.

`print(1,2) if 0 else 3,4` is equivalent to print `(1,2) if 0 else 3, 4`.
print statement receives two "arguments", first contains ternary statement, second is constant expression.